# Forloop with Limit

Tags: php

I am trying to loop stars(filled & unfilled) out of 5 in PHP. So if rating is 3 then 3 filled stars and 2 unfilled stars out of 5.

[image]

```
$rating = 3;    
@for($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++)
<img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/star.png')}}">
<!--<img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/ustar.png')}}"> --> //unfilled
@endfor
```

Comment: Please put conditions in the loop . So you can limit the result as per your need . thanks

Comment: `if($x <= $rating){ //normal star }else{ //the unfilled one }`

Comment: No problem @Zack...glad to help

Comment: You can do it without a for loop...

Answer (score 0):

```
$rating = 3;
for ($x=1; $x<=5; $x++) {
    echo $x<=$rating ? "<img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/star.png')}}">" : "<img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/ustar.png')}}">";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rating = 3;
unfilled=5-$rating;    
for($x = 1; $x <= $rating; $x++)
{
echo "<img src='{{ URL::asset('assets/star.png')}}'>";
}
for($x = 1; $x <= $unfilled; $x++)
{
echo "<img src='{{ URL::asset('assets/ustar.png')}}'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in PHP or anything, but can you just make 5 rating pictures and pick the picture based on $rating.

```
$pics = array('assets/1star.png', 'assets/2star.png', 'assets/3star.png', 'assets/4star.png','assets/5star.png');
$rating = 3;
$pickedpic = $pics[$rating];
```

Just another thought. This would prevent loading 5x pngs per each rating

Answer (score 0):

As you fall out of the first loop, `$x` still has a useful value. By omitting the first variable in the next for loop you can make use of the value of $x from the end of the first loop.

```
$rating = 3;
@for($x = 1; $x <= $rating; $x++)
    <img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/star.png')}}">
@endfor
@for(; $x <= 5; $x++)
    <img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/ustar.png')}}">
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

Two loops. One for filled and the remaining for unfilled:

```
$rating = 3;
@for($x = 1; $x <= $rating; $x++)
    <img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/star.png')}}">
@endfor
@for($x = $rating +1; $x <= 5; $x++)
    <!--<img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/ustar.png')}}"> --> //unfilled
@endfor
```